# Same elements have different children

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
tileElement = $('#game').find('#grid').find('#gridTable').find('.tile[data-tile-x=' + tile.x + '][data-tile-y=' + tile.y + ']');
tileElement1 = this.table.find('.tile[data-tile-x=' + tile.x + '][data-tile-y=' + tile.y + ']');
```

These two JQuery elements have the same selectors according to the debugger, yet the first one contains the children that I expected to be in there and the second one has no children at all. The method chain is the same in both cases, the only difference is that `this.table` is a passed reference from the parent class. What am I missing?

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to chain `.find('#grid').find('#gridTable')`. If it's an ID, just select it directly since only one element can have a given ID. For example, `$('#gridTable')`

Comment: What is `this.table` exactly?

Comment: @MikeC, I know, but it was passed down through a few classes anyway, and it should be faster since it doesn't have to filter the entire DOM, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `this.table` is `#gridTable` found by the ID after injecting a Handlebars template into `#grid`

Comment: @Krzaku That all depends on the browser. It would make sense for the browser implementors to create some kind of hash for every ID which would be faster. Generally speaking, `document.getElementById` (which is what jQuery uses underneath) is faster than any other forms of DOM traversal.

Comment: In fact `$('#id1').find('#id2')` may be **slower** than `$('#id2')`, because after finding `id2` it has to check that it's inside `id1`.

Comment: Can you make a Stack Snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I'll remember that, thanks. I think I know what the problem might be with my code. Do I have to update the reference to an element after I updated it using `html()`, so it shows new children that have been added?

Comment: You don't need to do that for the element itself, but if you have references to any of its children you need to update them.

Comment: When you use `.html()`, all the HTML within that element is reparsed from scratch, and new elements are created for the contents.

Comment: If you want to update the contents without invalidating references to parts that don't change, you should use methods like `.append()` and `.prepend()` to insert new objects at specific places in the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, that's it. `#gridTable` is in a template that I regenerate every time I need to add a new element to the table, so like you said, `this.table` is no longer valid after I inject the template into the DOM. Extracting `#gridTable` and putting it in a main template fixes this.